# How to Design reports in progress App Builder?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I just want to design new report in progress app builder.

Example:
I just want to pass employee number as a input parameter and get the respective  employee details in excel sheet. for that how to write code in progress. please see the image.

[image: app builder prob]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Of course I've no idea how your db is actually organized but something like the following will export all of the "employee" records matching the employee number passed to the procedure.  The output will be a CSV file suitable for Excel to open.  It should give you some ideas about the syntax that you might like to start with.

```
define variable employeeNum as integer no-undo.

update employeeNum.

run exportEmployees ( input employeeNum ).


procedure exportEmployee:

  define input parameter empNum as integer no-undo.

  define buffer employee for employee.

  output to value( "employee.csv" ).
  for each employee no-lock where employee.employeeId = empNum:
    export delimiter "," employee.
  end.
  output close.

  return.

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get data to excel is to use EXPORT.

Ie

```
OUTPUT TO file.csv.
FOR EACH Customer NO-LOCK:
    EXPORT DELIMITER ";" Customer.
END.
OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

That will export without any formatting though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of excel you can try com-handles to directly interact with it instead of opening a saved file.

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/21671

Your code would be similar to the example above, but you would change the /* Add Data */ section to something like the following.

```
FOR EACH EMP NO-LOCK    
   WHERE EMP.EMPNO = INTEGER(EMPNO:SCREEN-VALUE):

    /* Add data */
    ASSIGN chWorksheet:Range("B1"):VALUE = EMP.ENAME
           chWorksheet:Range("B2"):VALUE = EMP.SAL.

END.
```

This assumes the fill-in is called "EMPNO" and your EMPNO field is an integer.